# Текущий каталог для процесса и для каждого диска, WinAPI

Tags: visual-c++, winapi

У меня есть задача по Windows API: "Определить и вывести текущий каталог для процесса и для каждого диска".

Правильно ли я понял и выполнил задачу? Что  значит для каждого диска?

```
void get_current_dir(TCHAR dirname[]) {
  TCHAR *fileExt = NULL;
  TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
  GetFullPathName(dirname, MAX_PATH, szDir, &fileExt);
  _tprintf(_T("Full path: %s \nFilename: %s\n"), szDir, fileExt);
}
int main () {
  TCHAR dirname[] = TEXT("C:");
  get_current_dir(dirname);
}
```

**UPD:**

Вроде разобрался как получить текущий каталог текущего диска.

```
void get_current_process_dir() {
  char* buffer = new char[MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, buffer);
  CharToOemA(buffer, buffer);
  cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Comment: @khusaenov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, текущим каталогом процесса является тот, в который сохраняется файл, если сохранять его с указанием имени без диска и пути. Текущим каталогом диска является тот, в который сохраняется файл, если сохранять его с указанием диска и имени, но без пути.

Comment: @maxleo: А чем это противоречит коду в вопросе?

Comment: @VladD, он нашел второй (но только для одного диска), считая при этом, что нашел первый.

Comment: @maxleo: А, в этом смысле да.

Comment: @maxleo @VladD я не особо понял, не могли бы вы помочь разобраться, дать более развернутую информацию, с примером о том, что такое текущий каталог диска и текущий каталог процесса.